# How to use the [plain] option in beamer note page?

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to use the `plain` style for `beamer` note pages but it does not work. I tried:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}

\note[plain]{note text}
\end{document}
```

but it still produces the default style. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `plain` option has to be passed to the `note page` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}[plain]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content
\end{frame}

\note{note text}

\end{document}
```

Comment: hey thanks! DO you also know what's the difference between [default] and [compress]? They look the same to me

Comment: @murena they're basically the same. `compress` tries to squeeze more material in than `default`.

Comment: so maybe I can't see the difference because I only have small bits of note text.

Comment: @murena yes, for small bits of text there's no noticeable difference.